# How can we write two @beforeTest methods in Unit Testcase?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I have two methods in my test case. I want to use two different `@BeforeTest` or `@BeforeMethod` methods for each one of my Test methods.

I wrote two `@BeforeMethod` methods in my unit test class, but both methods are executed for every Unit Test method execution.

So how can we declare the `@BeforeMethod` methods to execute for specific test methods individually?

My Unit Test Class look like:

```
public class MyUnitTest{

  String userName = null;
  String password = null;

  // Method 1
  @Parameters({"userName"})
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod1(String userName){
      userName = userName;
  }

  @Parameters({"userName"})
  @Test
  public void unitTest1(String userNameTest){
      System.out.println("userName ="+userName);
  }


  // Method 2
  @Parameters({"userName","password"})
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod2(String userName,String password){
      this.userName = userName;
      this.password = password;
  }

  @Parameters({"userName","password"})
  @Test
  public void unitTest2(String userNameTest,String passwordTest){
      System.out.println("userName ="+this.userName+" \t Password ="+this.password);
  }

}
```

Is there a way to make:

1. `beforeMethod1` method only execute for `unitTest1()` method?
2. `beforeMethod2` method only execute for `unitTest2()` method?

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:

- You can declare the @BeforeMethod with a Method parameter, check the name of that method and if it's unitTest1, invoke beforeMethod1() and if it's unitTest2, invoke beforeMethod2(). This would probably not be my first choice since it's a bit fragile if you change the names of your methods.
- Put these methods and their before method in separate classes, possibly sharing a common superclass.